# User-specific database records

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

This is more of a theoretical questions. Anyways,
Assume that I have a database (50 tables)
And Data in ALL of those tables should be hold specifically to one user. 
What I mean is, usually we do foreign keys for each table that is user-specific. and retrieving data using something like:

```
select Column1,Col2,Col3 from Table where UserId=@UserId
```

This clutters queries significantly. Is the other way of storing such data?

Comment: You can make views to clean the queries. For example if you have `customers`, `customers_addresses`, `customer_phones`, ... you can create `customers_full`. This would make any query about customers cleaner, instead of N joins you would have 1 view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to has a name. It's called [multi-tenant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). The link gives some general information on multi-tenant structures.

This all depends on your RDBMS though. Oracle provides a tool which makes this very easy. 
The

```
WHERE User_ID = @User_ID
```

becomes a *policy* which you can *apply* to tables. You also create a protected stored procedure to update @User_id to ensure that it cannot be changed without authority. Then every query to a table with such a policy adds the *where clause* in the background. It's automatic and there's no way to avoid it.

Comment: In Oracle it's called Virtual Private Database or Row Level Security. Depends on how old the person is you're talking to.

Answer (score 2):

There might be other ways, but I wouldn't say they are better.  If every record in every table needs to belong to a specific user then you need a way to define that.

A possible method to reduce the number of UserId columns would be if you have child tables and you simply assumed that the parent table defined ownership and that it was implied that it's child records belonged to that user.

Example:

```
CarMake:
MakeId
MakeName
UserId

CarModel:
ModelId
MakeId
ModelName
```

Notice that CarModel does not have a UserId column, but you could assume that it inherits the same UserId of the parent CarMake record.  If you cannot assume that children should always inherit the parent UserId then your original method is best.

Comment: +1 This is a good suggestion regardless. It gives you a lot lower chance of having stale data.